# How to post to a facebook page

Tags: django, facebook

I need to post a status update of one of my facebook page when I create a model into my django project, but I don't know how to do it using the new facebook graph api:

http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.py

can you explain to me how to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you had a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api to see how the base implemetation works? Also, looking at the code for the Django test Client might show you how to make a POST to Facebook from your server-side code - http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/client.py#L295

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a classy site that allows facebook sharing: http://www.news.com.au/national/topless-hero-tash-bennett-saves-neighbours-from-fire/story-e6frfkvr-1225864785973

On the story, there's a link to "post a story to facebook", if that's what you want to do:

http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.news.com.au/national/topless-hero-tash-bennett-saves-neighbours-from-fire/story-e6frfkvr-1225864785973
You can reverse-engineer the protocol: `'http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=%s'%page_I_want_linked_to`

Make sure you click the link with a browser logged onto facebook; or use mechanize (and your Mozilla cookie jar) to do the job.

Comment: This is not what I want, because I actually want to post a link to one of my facebook pages but without user interaction (with correct permission, obviously). However thanks for the reply